# Component props and data not being updated by parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I made a codepen of my issue here https://codepen.io/stevemr/pen/VNQbYe

I have a root Vue instance which maintains the props for a component, VideoPlayer. My root instance has a method called setVideo, which is just assigning some dummy values right now.

Here's the object I'm using in the data of the root instance:

```
video: {
    drive: '',
    filename: '',
    mediaType: '',
},
```

Here's the setVideo function:

```
setVideo: function() {
    // Get the drive, filename, and mediaType
    this.video.drive = 'hdd1';
    this.video.filename = 'game-of-thrones_s01e04.mp4';
    this.video.mediaType = 'show';

    // Hide all modals and trigger the display of the video player
    Event.trigger('hideModal');
    Event.trigger('displayVideoPlayer');
},
```

The Event class is just a wrapper for basic Vue events:

```
window.Event = new class {
    constructor() {
        this.vue = new Vue();
    }

    trigger(event, data = null) {
        this.vue.$emit(event, data);
    }

    listen(event, callback) {
        this.vue.$on(event, callback);
    }
};
```

Here's the DOM where my VideoPlayer component is initialized:

```html
<video-player
    v-bind:drive="video.drive"
    v-bind:filename="video.filename"
    v-bind:media-type="video.mediaType"
></video-player>
```

And finally, here's my VideoPlayer component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="movie-container">
            <div
                class="video-loader top-most"
                v-if="showVideoPlayer && !loaded"
            ></div>
            <video
                id="video-player"
                ref="video"
                v-if="showVideoPlayer && src !== ''"
                class="top-most"
                v-bind:class="{ hidden: !loaded }"
                v-on:click="togglePlay"
                controls
                autoplay
            >
                <source v-bind:src="src" v-bind:type="videoType"></source>
            </video>
        </div>

        <div id="time-range-container" v-if="showTimeRange">
            <input
                id="time-range"
                ref="timeRange"
                type="range"
                min="0"
                v-bind:max="duration"
                step="30"
                v-model:value="currentTime"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'drive',
            'filename',
            'mediaType',
        ],

        data() {
            return {
                currentTime: 0,
                duration: 0,
                loaded: false,
                showTimeRange: false,
                showVideoPlayer: false,
            }
        },

        computed: {
            src: function() {
                if(this.filename !== '') {
                    return
                        '/video/' + this.drive +
                        '/' + this.mediaType +
                        's/' + this.filename;
                }

                return '';
            },

            videoType: function() {
                var ext = this.filename.split('.')[1];
                var type = '';

                switch(ext) {
                    case 'mk4':
                    case 'm4v':
                        type = 'webm';
                        break;
                    case 'avi':
                        type = 'ogg';
                        break;
                    default:
                        type = ext;
                }

                return 'video/' + type;
            },
        },

        created() {
            Event.listen('displayVideoPlayer', this.display);
        },

        methods: {
            display: function() {
                if(this.src === '') {
                    return;
                }

                this.showVideoPlayer = true;
                this.loaded = false;

                var self = this;

                setTimeout(function() {
                    var interval = setInterval(function() {
                        var video = self.$refs.video;
                        if(video.readyState > 0) {
                            self.loaded = true;
                            self.duration = Math.round(video.duration);
                            self.currentTime = video.currentTime;
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }, 800);
            },

            togglePlay: function() {
                var video = this.$refs.video;

                if(video.paused) {
                    video.play();
                }

                if(!video.paused) {
                    video.pause();
                }
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

When setVideo is called it should set the VideoPlayer component's props to the dummy values and then the video player should be displayed. But instead when the displayVideoPlayer event is fired, the component props are still set to their default values (empty strings). Most importantly, the src computed property is not being updated before the display method is called, so the display function immediately returns without doing anything.

It's like my component's props and data aren't being updated, even though I can see with the dev tools that they are. It's like it's just not happening fast enough or something.

I've tried making src part of the component's data and setting it in the display function with another function, setSrc. But the same thing happened.

I've also tried moving Event.listen('displayVideoPlayer', this.display); into mounted() instead of created(), also did not fix anything.

If you look at the codepen, the first time you click the button to trigger the setVideo function, the video player component should be displayed, instead it takes 2 clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is a race condition between Vue updates the value and You call `display` method:

```
display: function() {
  console.log(this.src) // ""
  setTimeout(() => console.log(this.src)) // "/video/hdd1/shows/game-of-thrones_s01e04.mp4"
  if(this.src === '') {
    return
  }
```

This mean you call `display` method before the value is update.

One way to solve you is add some delay before your call `display` method:

```
setVideo: function() {
  this.video.drive = 'hdd1'
  this.video.filename = 'game-of-thrones_s01e04.mp4'
  this.video.mediaType = 'show'
  setTimeout(() => {
    Event.trigger('displayVideoPlayer')
  })
```

But I think this might get more problems in the future. If you want to rely on props then you should use watcher pattern instead:

```
watch: {
  src (src) {
    if(src === '') {
      return
    }
    // ... display
  }
}
```

Or pass those values through your event not on props like:

```
Event.trigger('displayVideoPlayer', this.video)
```

Comment: I tried moving the props into the component's data and passing the video object in a separate event, before displayVideoPlayer is triggered. That seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!